# MySQL database offline to online synchronization

Tags: mysql

I am new to programming. I have a web application that does not need a constant internet connection. I want to synchronize my local database to a remote database automatically whenever internet is available, for example, `I inserted a data to my local database, and when internet connection is available, I want that data to be reflected to my remote database as well`. Is there any way to do this using MySQL only?

Comment: Yup. Replication: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication.html

Comment: @ceejayoz does replication automatically synchronize my database for me whenever my web application is connected to the internet or do I need to write a script for that?

Comment: You'd need to set up some automation. That said, what you want to do is *typically* unnecessary and complex. You'd often be better off building a concept of database migrations into the app you're building.

Comment: I encountered a similar problem and ended up solving it by setting up a Master-to-Master Replication. Just follow this tutorial https://www.vpsserver.com/community/tutorials/9/setup-a-master-to-master-replication-between-two-mariadb-servers/